# ListView ImageCells' images not showing in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms app with a `ListView` with `ImageCell`s. The images in it are seen in Android and iOS, but not in UWP.

the pertinent code:

```
imageCell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, theImagePropertyName);
```

and the property:

```
return ImageSource.FromUri(uri);
```

`uri` is the correct uri (as shown by a breakpoint), it is an external uri `https://blahblahblah.com`, and as said - it works in Android and iOS. I've tried an external static uri, an internal (`ms-appx:///Assets/a.png`) uri...

What might be the problem?

Comment: Have you placed your images in the application´s root folder?

Comment: @JesusAngulo I'm sorry, I wasn't clear - the uri is external (`https://blahblahblah.com`). I now edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: Have you set **Internet (InternetClient)** permission in your manifest?

Comment: @JesusAngulo Yes. (It is actually set by default in the template.)

Comment: Can you try with a static remote image just to focus on binding problems. `<Image Source="https://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png" />`

Comment: @JesusAngulo I tried with a static image. Doesn't help. (By the way - your link is a 404.)

Comment: a static remote image doesn't show?

Comment: @JesusAngulo Correct.

Comment: Did you try my solution? Not sure if thats what you want but I'm pretty positive it will work

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. My image works in all 3 platforms. May be you want to share your project?

Comment: @JesusAngulo As a side note: `https://www.xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png`. is working. Somehow it seems you need to add `www` or it will result in a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I have this happen to me in my iOS app. I don't know why it's occurring. The only way I was able to solve it was to use [FFimageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) or I also was able to create my old lazy load images implementation, but `FFImageLoading` seems to be a bit better. The implementation is pretty easy and all you do is replace the datatype from `Xamarin.Forms.Image` to `FFImageLoading.CachedImage` (or if you're at the platform level something similar).

Sorry I couldn't give you a "this is why ____" I was unable to figure out why it's happening. You have an image, you set source, boom common sense tells you it should load. But I have the exact same problem on xamarin forms listview on iOS (at least). This was only way to solve it.

**I have no affiliation with FFImageLoading**

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not interested in a 3rd party library.

Comment: Ok can you update your question when you find a solution? I have similar problems with iOS.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet do you want to share your solution? I cannot reproduce it in my environment

Comment: Did you implement FFImageLoading?